# Using Python, could I automate the process of getting excel data into a CRM system?

Tags: python, excel

I've done a little basic coding in Java, VBA and C++ before but still a complete newbie, I'm trying to understand what exactly it is that I could do with Python and how it would be useful.

For example, at my appointment-setting job I get customer data in an Excel sheet from my boss, that I'm supposed to put into the CRM system before calling them. It takes me probably at least 5 minutes each time and it's very tedious. Could I automate this process using Python? I've been looking into learning Python recently and thought this might be a good first goal-project in that case, if it's possible and not too difficult to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CRM is, but pulling excel content into your python program is easy. I have used this (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) for processing excel content in the past.

Comment: Sorry I should have explained, CRM is short for customer relationship management, so it's a customer relationship management-system I want to put it into.

Comment: So could I use that data to put it into the web-based CRM-system in the correct places? Names where you're supposed to write names, phone numbers where you're supposed to put the phone numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Python for this. [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/) is a good resource for getting started. Once you understand how to do this, you need to find out if your CRM has some sort of API or tool that will allow you to post data with your Python code. Chances are good that it does.

Comment: Ah, so it kind of depends on the CRM-system? The system is in the web browser, couldn't I just tell the program to look for certain keywords in the browser and input the data? Like tell the program to look for the word "Name" in Chrome and have it input the name in the empty box to the right of it?

Comment: You can do that with JavaScript, but it's not permanent. You need to post to the server. What CRM platform do you use?

Comment: We use Podio and it seems there's an API for Python in it.

Comment: How do you mean that I need to post it to the server?

Comment: When you submit a form in the browser, you are usually making some sort of HTTP request that either sends data to the server or retrieves data from the server. The Podio API will allow you to do that without filling out a form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answers.

Comment: I'm happy to help. If you want to learn more about HTTP and web servers, I recommend [Udacity's free course on HTTP](https://www.udacity.com/course/http-web-servers--ud303). The course is taught in Python, so that's another plus. As for APIs, I think the Udacity courses may be a bit too advanced, so try out one of [Codeacademy's API courses with Python](https://www.codecademy.com/apis) to get a feel for how APIs work. I think the these resources in addition to Automate the Boring Stuff with Python will set you up for success with this and later projects.